# Google Analytics - Create custom report based on 2 events

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics, analytics-events

I am trying to create a report based on 2 events in Google Analytics. Event A is triggered when a user views a contact form and Event B is triggered when the user submits the form.

What would be the best way to create a report which displays the conversion rate based on the data received from Events A and B above?

So basically the percentage of users that viewed the form and then went on to submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do people view the contact form? In a specific page or in lot of pages?
After the submission do they see a thank you page?

In that case you should use Funnel when creating an event. And you'll find reports under Conversions -> Goals -> Funnel Visualization.

The other solution is to create a segment where you include all the people that converted Event A. Then, activate that segment and look at Goal Overview for Event B or make a Custom Report.

Comment: Hi Lucgenti, Thanks for your reply. The form appears inside a lightbox the first time a user visits on the site on the 3rd page that they view.

The form is submitted using AJAX so the event is fired once the form is successfully submitted.

Comment: I suggest you to add a virtual Pageview `ga('send', 'pageview', 'page path');` to your form, then add a thank you page (even virtual this one) and track the funnel. Or just use the segments. Try and see what's better for you.